# How to transform soap fault message in wso2

Tags: xslt, soap, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm getting two different response in two versions of WSO2 esb 6.5.0 and 4.9.0.

**6.5 Response with wrong header**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Fault</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <axis2ns13:sdpFault xmlns:axis2ns13="http://www.service.lk">
                <axis2ns13:Code>99</axis2ns3:Code>
                <axis2ns13:Name>wrong</axis2ns3:Name>
            </axis2ns13:sdpFault>
        </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

What i need is getting response like below.
**4.9.0 response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <soapenv:Body>
                <soapenv:Fault>
                    <soapenv:Code>
                        <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Sender</soapenv:Value>
                    </soapenv:Code>
                    <soapenv:Reason>
                        <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en">Fault</soapenv:Reason>
                    <soapenv:Detail>
                        <axis2ns1:sdpFault xmlns:axis2ns1="http:service.lk">
                            <axis2ns1:Code>13</axis2ns1:Code>
                            <axis2ns1:Name>wrong</axis2ns1:Name>
                        </axis2ns1:sdpFault>
                    </soapenv:Detail>
                </soapenv:Fault>
            </soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Hi Rest, It is hard to answer this question without knowing the sequence of events. You are sending a out message, something goes wrong at the endpoint returning an error and WSO2 returns the error above? Please elaborate

Comment: hii thanks jan. what exactly need to know? In here that response given by wso2 after receiving the client response, but problem is  TCP dump is exactly same both version but when came to the wso2 it will change.

Comment: I could assume you are sending this onward, but the response is a bit odd with all the axis2ns1 parts which seem to originate from within the ESB so it's better to ask.

Comment: perhaps you can specify 'format=soap11' when sending this onward? For instance: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Default+Endpoint

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem of different version of WSO2 products and i believe it shouldn't be *"transformed"*. The first response you get (from EI 6.5.0) is in *SOAP 1.1* version, and the second, (from ESB 4.9.0) is in *SOAP 1.2*. So its looks like you generate that response using **Fault Mediator** but using two different versions. Simply change the version in that Fault mediator, according to this documentation: [WSO2EI 6.5.0 Fault Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Fault+Mediator) and [WSO2ESB 4.9.0 Fault Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Fault+Mediator)

If that doesn't help, you need provide more information, what is going in the WSO2 mediation sequence.

Comment: Thanks you @tmoasz for your reply. actually I'm not using any  Fault Mediator in both versions.my configuration are exactly same in both versions, and one of my problem  is why is that two different response they gave me in two versions with same payload, and other one is   i can't transform 6.5 response because this <axis2ns1:Code> axis2ns1 value will increase per request.so i can't transformed that.